Replacing values in a flattened JSON based on two conditions
I have managed to flatten a JSON with the help of jolt.
The flattened JSON should now serve as an INPUT JSON
for the following case:
Each time when the condition
"values-*-identifier" = "colour"  AND  "values-*-value" = "green" 

is fullfilled the value "green" should be replaced by "gre".
That means the spec has to execute an if/else with "AND" and has to compare the index within the key, which should have the same number, in order to guarantee that the value belongs to the identifier.
INPUT JSON:
{
  "values_0_identifier": "country",
  "values_0_value": "red",
  "values_0_value_unit_key": "",
  "values_0_language": "",
  "values_1_identifier": "metal",
  "values_1_value": "red",
  "values_1_value_unit_key": "",
  "values_1_language": "",
  "values_2_identifier": "colour",
  "values_2_value": "green",
  "values_2_value_unit_key": "",
  "values_2_language": ""
}

DESIRED OUTPUT
{
  "values_0_identifier": "country",
  "values_0_value": "red",
  "values_0_value_unit_key": "",
  "values_0_language": "",
  "values_1_identifier": "metal",
  "values_1_value": "red",
  "values_1_value_unit_key": "",
  "values_1_language": "",
  "values_2_identifier": "colour",
  "values_2_value": "gre",
  "values_2_value_unit_key": "",
  "values_2_language": ""
}

I tried this spec so far
[
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "values_2_value": {
        "green": {
          "values_2_identifier": {
            "colour": {
              "#gre": "value_2_identifier"
            }
          }
        }
      },
      "*": "&"
    }
  }
]

1st issue: my if_else condition has no result. It seems, that it is swallowing the mapped value.
2nd issue: Even when this spec should work. Of course I don't want to specify the value "-2-" within the key. Here, some kind of wildcard like -- should work. Whereby -- should naturally always have the same index.
Each kind of help will be highly appreciated. Thanks in advance for any kind of hint.

You can start grouping by indexes 0,1,2 through use of

&(2,1) : going 2 levels up the tree and picking the 1st asterisk replacement
&(2,2) : going 2 levels up the tree and picking the 2nd asterisk replacement

representations such as
[
  { //group by indexes 0,1,2
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "values_*_*": {
        "*": {
          "@1": "&(2,1).&(2,2)"
        }
      }
    }
  },
  { //
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "*": {
        "*": "values_&1_&", //other attributes
        "value": { "": "" }, //get rid of extra "value" attributes
        "identifier": {
          "@": "values_&2_&", // to replicate "identifier" itself
          "*": { // if identifier IS NOT colour 
            "@2,value": "values_&3_value"
          },
          "colour": {
            "@2,value": {
              "green": {
                "#gre": "values_&5_value"
              },
              "*": { // value IS NOT green
                "@1": "values_&5_value"
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
]

the demo on the site https://jolt-demo.appspot.com/ is :


Thanks Barbaros for your help and for correcting my input JSON (my bad, sorry).

There is a small little issue within your solution. When the identifier is not "colour" the return value of "value" corresonds to the value of "identifier". I know that the answer is in this part of your spec , second spec      @1": "values_&3_value"       but I did not manage to sort it out.
